# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dtd html 4.0 transitional//EN"> causes jquery dialog not to show

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using this doctype (DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dtd html 4.0 transitional//EN") and the css below to freeze first 4 columns and the header row in an ASP.NET gridview (the way "freeze panes" works in Excel). It works on IE8 which all my users use exclusively. Problem is this doctype causes a jquery modal dialog not to show on IE8. The screen grays mind you, but the dialog doesnt show. (The page doesnt have any other CSS that could interfere with the dialog)

```
.Freezing
{
position:relative ;
top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
z-index: 10;  
}  

.FreezingCol 
{ 
    z-index: 1; 
    left: expression( 
    document.getElementById("freezingDiv").scrollLeft); 
    position: relative; 
}
```

Now when I change doctype to strict or even this (DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">), the jquery dialog works but the column freezing stops working in IE8.

FYI the dialog works in other browsers.

Adding code below to the dialog definition makes the dialog show up but at the bottom of the page (not screen) after the gray area ends, which is no good. it should show up in the center of the screen.

```
open: function(event, ui) {
$(this).parent().css('position', 'fixed'); //d
}
```

I kinda know doctype transitional = quirks mode, but need to use it for the column and header freezing in IE. I'm guessing however that I can make some changes in the dialog section of jquery-ui.css to make it work with doctype transitional mode. I'm not an expert in CSS. Things I've already tried are removing "overflow: hidden;" and specifying "height : 300px;" in .ui-dialog-content. Didnt help, but I'm willing to try them again in combination with something else.

TIA to all experts out there.

```
* jQuery UI Dialog 1.8.24
*
* Copyright 2012, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* http://jquery.org/license
*
* http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#theming
*/

.ui-dialog { position: absolute; padding: .2em; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar { padding: .4em 1em; position: relative;  }

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title { float: left; margin: .1em 16px .1em 0; } 

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { position: absolute; right: .3em; top: 50%; width: 19px; margin: -10px 0 0 0; padding: 1px; height: 18px; }

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close span { display: block; margin: 1px; }

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:hover, .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:focus { padding: 0; }

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content { position: relative; border: 0; padding: .5em 1em; background: none; overflow: auto; zoom: 1; }

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane { text-align: left; border-width: 1px 0 0 0; background-image: none; margin: .5em 0 0 0; padding: .3em 1em .5em .4em; }

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset { float: right; }

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button { margin: .5em .4em .5em 0; cursor: pointer; }

.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se { width: 14px; height: 14px; right: 3px; bottom: 3px; }

.ui-draggable .ui-dialog-titlebar { cursor: move; }
```

Comment: "Dtd html 4.0 transitional"? Why the weird casing?

Comment: This was somebody else's old code. Changed it proper casing, still have the same results. Thanks. //W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN".